# How to install Prometheus with ingress enabled on AWS with Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, kubernetes, amazon-route53, prometheus

For example, my Route 53 Hosted Zone is `myzone.com`. Created a Kubernetes cluster by kops with cluster full name: `earth.myzone.com`.

I tried to install Prometheus this way:

```
helm install prometheus \
  --set alertmanager.ingress.enabled=true \
  --set alertmanager.ingress.hosts=[alertmanager.earth.myzone.com] \
  --set pushgateway.ingress.enabled=true \
  --set pushgateway.ingress.hosts=[pushgateway.earth.myzone.com] \
  --set server.ingress.enabled=true \
  --set server.ingress.hosts=[server.earth.myzone.com]
```

Got error:

```
zsh: no matches found: alertmanager.ingress.hosts=[alertmanager.earth.myzone.com]
```

Or name the subdomain under `myzone.com`?

```
helm install prometheus \
  --set alertmanager.ingress.enabled=true \
  --set alertmanager.ingress.hosts=[alertmanager.myzone.com] \
  --set pushgateway.ingress.enabled=true \
  --set pushgateway.ingress.hosts=[pushgateway.myzone.com] \
  --set server.ingress.enabled=true \
  --set server.ingress.hosts=[server.myzone.com]
```

Also the same error.

If deploy an application by deployment and service manifest files with ELB, create a DNS record is necessary like `aws route53 change-resource-record-sets ...` first. Then url will like:

app.earth.myzone.com

But if want to deploy `Prometheus` only, how to do?

---

## Edit

Use @fiunchinho 's method to run again, successfully completed:

```
$ helm install prometheus \
>   --set alertmanager.ingress.enabled=true \
>   --set "alertmanager.ingress.hosts={alertmanager.earth.myzone.com}" \
>   --set pushgateway.ingress.enabled=true \
>   --set "pushgateway.ingress.hosts={pushgateway.earth.myzone.com}" \
>   --set server.ingress.enabled=true \
>   --set "server.ingress.hosts={server.earth.myzone.com}"
NAME:   auxilliary-pronghorn
E0129 01:41:06.224401   15782 portforward.go:303] error copying from remote stream to local connection: readfrom tcp4 127.0.0.1:42993->127.0.0.1:55840: write tcp4 127.0.0.1:42993->127.0.0.1:55840: write: broken pipe
LAST DEPLOYED: Mon Jan 29 01:41:05 2018
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/Service
NAME                                                TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)   AGE
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-alertmanager        ClusterIP  100.68.246.60   <none>       80/TCP    1s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-kube-state-metrics  ClusterIP  None            <none>       80/TCP    1s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-node-exporter       ClusterIP  None            <none>       9100/TCP  1s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-pushgateway         ClusterIP  100.69.211.226  <none>       9091/TCP  1s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-server              ClusterIP  100.71.5.220    <none>       80/TCP    1s

==> v1beta1/DaemonSet
NAME                                           DESIRED  CURRENT  READY  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  NODE SELECTOR  AGE
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-node-exporter  2        2        0      2           0          <none>         0s

==> v1beta1/Deployment
NAME                                                DESIRED  CURRENT  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-alertmanager        1        1        1           0          0s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-kube-state-metrics  1        1        1           0          0s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-pushgateway         1        1        1           0          0s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-server              1        1        1           0          0s

==> v1beta1/Ingress
NAME                                          HOSTS                                   ADDRESS  PORTS  AGE
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-alertmanager  alertmanager.earth.myzone.com  80       0s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-pushgateway   pushgateway.earth.myzone.com   80       0s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-server        server.earth.myzone.com        80       0s

==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME                                                             READY  STATUS             RESTARTS  AGE
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-node-exporter-kjp25              0/1    ContainerCreating  0         0s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-node-exporter-r2sfn              0/1    ContainerCreating  0         0s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-alertmanager-684bb4bf8d-lq5z9    0/2    Pending            0         0s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-kube-state-metrics-69478d6lwdpq  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         0s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-pushgateway-6f97d7bc4d-jvj2c     0/1    ContainerCreating  0         0s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-server-65974d66bc-876rt          0/2    Pending            0         0s

==> v1/ConfigMap
NAME                                          DATA  AGE
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-alertmanager  1     1s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-server        3     1s

==> v1/PersistentVolumeClaim
NAME                                          STATUS   VOLUME  CAPACITY  ACCESS MODES  STORAGECLASS  AGE
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-alertmanager  Pending  gp2     1s
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-server        Pending  gp2     1s

NOTES:
The Prometheus server can be accessed via port 80 on the following DNS name from within your cluster:
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-server.default.svc.cluster.local

From outside the cluster, the server URL(s) are:
http://server.earth.myzone.com


The Prometheus alertmanager can be accessed via port 80 on the following DNS name from within your cluster:
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-alertmanager.default.svc.cluster.local

From outside the cluster, the alertmanager URL(s) are:
http://alertmanager.earth.myzone.com


The Prometheus PushGateway can be accessed via port 9091 on the following DNS name from within your cluster:
auxilliary-pronghorn-prometheus-pushgateway.default.svc.cluster.local

From outside the cluster, the pushgateway URL(s) are:
http://pushgateway.earth.myzone.com

For more information on running Prometheus, visit:
https://prometheus.io/
```

(I changed my real domain to a fake one here)

But when I tried to access the three services:

- http://server.earth.myzone.com
- http://alertmanager.earth.myzone.com
- http://pushgateway.earth.myzone.com

All of them can't been accessed. I don't know why. How to debug or find the reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error

> zsh: no matches found:
>   alertmanager.ingress.hosts=[alertmanager.earth.myzone.com]

is your shell, zsh, complaining because it believes you are trying to execute something related with it. Use quotes to avoid that. Furthermore, Helm expects curly braces for lists.

```
helm install prometheus \
  --set alertmanager.ingress.enabled=true \
  --set "alertmanager.ingress.hosts={alertmanager.earth.myzone.com}" \
  --set pushgateway.ingress.enabled=true \
  --set "pushgateway.ingress.hosts={pushgateway.earth.myzone.com}" \
  --set server.ingress.enabled=true \
  --set "server.ingress.hosts={server.earth.myzone.com}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have tried your way and it works this time! Another problem is I can't access the three services from browser. I added more detail in the question at `Edit` area.